# Tensorflow compare tf.int32 and tf.constant gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.4

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.int32 
b=tf.constant(3)
a==b
```

gives error instead of giving 'false'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 248, in __eq__
    and self._type_enum == as_dtype(other).as_datatype_enum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 536, in as_dtype
    if key == type_value:
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Why does this produce an error. I'm using tensorflow 0.8
Shouldn't one be able to check equality b/w any variables.

What I was trying to achieve was checking if an object is present in a list

```
a=tf.int32
b=[tf.constant(3),..other objects]
if a in b:
  do_something()
```

Answer (score 4):

This comparison does not make sense.

```
>>> a=tf.int32
>>> type(a)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes.DType'>
>>> print(a)
<dtype: 'int32'>
```

versus

```
>>> b=tf.constant(3)
>>> type(b)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
>>> print(b)
Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

What you see here, is that you are trying to compare a type (or class) with some form of instance of that class. There's no point in actually doing this. The error is thrown because `tf` has no idea how to actually perform this equality check.

**Update**

I see you updated your answer, so here the response:
While this is the correct syntax to check if an object is in a collection, my answer above still applies. The variable `a` does not refer to what you think it does. It holds a reference to the actual definition of the type `int32`. There is no point of looking for that in a tensor.

Comment: I was trying to check if an object is present in a list. (for i in list) if i is tf.int32 and list contains tf.constant(3) I am getting an error due to this equality check. Any idea how i can accomplish this

Comment: Since that might help other people, I'd suggest you open a new question for your actual issue. You can add a comment here so I can find the new question. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I really need to check if that object is present in that list. so I iterated and check if item 'is' tf.int32 instead of ==